# BeautifulSoup - Converting string values into int inside of nested for loop then sort

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a string value into an int within a scraped for loop in order to sort by the int ('views' within the below script).

Below is a condensed view of the problem. Inclduing a working script that returns the string, my failed attempt to fix the issue, and the desired output.

Working script that returns the string:

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pprint

res = requests.get('https://www.searchenginejournal.com/category/news/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('h2', class_='sej-ptitle')
subtext = soup.find_all('ul', class_='sej-meta-cells')


def sort_stories_by_views(sejlist):
    return sorted(sejlist, key=lambda k: k['views'], reverse=True)


def create_custom_sej(links, subtext):
    sej = []

    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].a.get('href', None)
        views = subtext[idx].find_all(
            'li')[2].text.strip().replace(' Reads', '')
        sej.append({'title': title, 'link': href, 'views': views})
    return sort_stories_by_views(sej)


create_custom_sej(links, subtext)
pprint.pprint(create_custom_sej(links, subtext))
```

Within the above, the output contains dictionaries that look like the below:

```
 {
'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-answers-if-site-section-can-impact-ranking-scores-of-
'title': 'Google Answers If Site Section Can Impact Ranking Score of Entire ''Site                ',
'views': '4.5K'
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
 {
'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-answers-if-site-section-can-impact-ranking-scores-of-
'title': 'Google Answers If Site Section Can Impact Ranking Score of Entire ''Site                ',
'views': '4500'
}
```

My failed attempt to fix the problem is below. The below script returns a single value, rather than the list of all applicable values, but i'm honestly not certain if i'm going about this in the correct way.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

res = requests.get('https://www.searchenginejournal.com/category/news/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('h2', class_='sej-ptitle')
subtext = soup.find_all('ul', class_='sej-meta-cells')


def sort_stories_by_views(sejlist):
    return sorted(sejlist, key=lambda k: k['views'], reverse=True)


def create_custom_sej(links, subtext):
    sej = []

    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].a.get('href', None)
        views = subtext[idx].find_all(
            'li')[2].text.strip().replace(' Reads', '').replace(' min  read', '')
# below is my unsuccessful attempt to change the strings to int
        for item in views:
            if views:
                multiplier = 1
                if views.endswith('K'):
                    multiplier = 1000
                    views = views[0:len(views)-1]
                return int(float(views) * multiplier)
            else:
                return views
        sej.append({'title': title, 'link': href, 'views': views})
    return sort_stories_by_views(sej)


create_custom_sej(links, subtext)
pprint.pprint(create_custom_sej(links, subtext))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to convert the views to integer:

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pprint

res = requests.get('https://www.searchenginejournal.com/category/news/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('h2', class_='sej-ptitle')
subtext = soup.find_all('ul', class_='sej-meta-cells')


def convert(views):
    if 'K' in views:
        return int( float( views.split('K')[0] ) * 1000 )
    else:
        return int(views)

def sort_stories_by_views(sejlist):
    return sorted(sejlist, key=lambda k: k['views'], reverse=True)


def create_custom_sej(links, subtext):
    sej = []

    for idx, item in enumerate(links):
        title = links[idx].getText()
        href = links[idx].a.get('href', None)
        views = item.parent.find('i', class_='sej-meta-icon fa fa-eye')
        views = views.find_next(text=True).split()[0] if views else '0'
        sej.append({'title': title, 'link': href, 'views': convert(views)})
    return sort_stories_by_views(sej)


create_custom_sej(links, subtext)
pprint.pprint(create_custom_sej(links, subtext))
```

Prints:

```
[{'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/microsoft-clarity-analytics/385867/',
  'title': 'Microsoft Announces Clarity – Free Website '
           'Analytics                ',
  'views': 11000},
 {'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/wordpress-5-6-feature-removed-for-subpar-experience/385414/',
  'title': 'WordPress 5.6 Feature Removed For Subpar '
           'Experience                ',
  'views': 7000},
 {'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/whatsapp-shopping-payment-customer-service/385362/',
  'title': 'WhatsApp Announces Shopping and Payment Tools for '
           'Businesses                ',
  'views': 6800},
 {'link': 'https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-noindex-meta-tag-proper-use/385538/',
  'title': 'Google Shares How Noindex Meta Tag Can Cause '
           'Issues                ',
  'views': 6500},

...and so on.
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate the help!